# is there an easier way to do this? radiogroups/buttons - android

Tags: android, fragment

I have two fragments and first fragment I have two pages and each page has at least two radio buttons with a question and those radio buttons are to choose your answer.
At the moment I have to use the if else function and using the `setText` to set the question and the answers for the radio button and when the right answer is clicked nothing will show until you go to the last page and click on show result.
Right now I have to keep on using if else and using `setOnClickListener` for all of them.
Also, by using the `setOnClickListener` it'll send a +1 result to my result page's variable.

Is there an easier way to do this?

This is what my code looks like

```
    if(fragmentNumber == 0)
    {
        ask_question.setText("Question1?");
        rb1.setText("Answer1");
        rb2.setText("Answer2");
        rb1.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ResultsFragment.Q1 = 1;
            }
        });
    }
    else if(fragmentNumber == 1)
    {
        ask_question.setText("Question2?");
        rb1.setText("Answer2-1");
        rb2.setText("Answer2-2");
        rb2.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ResultsFragment.Q2 = 1;
            }
        });

    }
```

Other than looking for an easier way to do this, I ran into another problem too.
Let me use examples.

E.g. if Q1 I got it right and Q2 I got it wrong when I go to show result I will get 1/2 which is good but if I go back to Q1 and click on the wrong answer on purpose then go back to show result, it'll still show 1/2 instead of 0/2 which means if the 1 is set into the variable then it'll stay there. I know if I use the `setOnclickListener` then I can set the other `radioButtons == 0` but that means inside each if statement there will be LOTS `setonClickListner` this is kind of another reason I'm seeking another easier result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for an easier way? Ok. In my opinion you should have a fragment(custom `QAFragment`) with only one page for a question and the answers.

```
public class QuestionFragment extends Fragment {

    public static QuestionFragment newInstance(String questionText, String[] answerArray) {
        QuestionFragment f = new QuestionFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("questionText", questionText);
        args.putStringArray("answerArray", answerArray);

        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    public String getQuestionText() {
        return getArguments().getString("questionText");
    }

    public String[] getAnswerArray() {
        return getArguments().getStringArray("answerArray");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View content = null;
        // TODO: inflate your content here, put your radios and question text

        final String questionText = getQuestionText();
        String[] answerArray = getAnswerArray();

        // TODO: set your question text with questionText value
        // TODO: set your asnwers with answerArray values

        RadioGroup radioGroup = null;
        // TODO: keep your radios with this radioGroup

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int radioButtonID) {
                String selectedAnswer = null;
                // TODO: if/else or switch statement on radioButtonId to get the selected answer

                            // Post the result to main activity to do extra operations or open new page.
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).postQAResult(questionText, selectedAnswer);
            }
        });

        return content;
    }
}
```

Add `postQAResult` method to your main activity to listen callbacks from your fragment.

```
public void postQAResult(String question, String asnwer) {
    // TODO: handle answer for the question. 
    // For example if you need to store answer you can use SharedPreferences to save. 
    // Or you can ask different questions for given answer.
}
```

Now you can add this qa fragment from your activity when you need a new question/answer page. for example;

```
    String questionText = "Any problem?";
    String[] answerArray = new String[]{"Yes","No"};
    QuestionFragment questionFragment = QuestionFragment.newInstance(questionText, answerArray);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, questionFragment, "UNIQUE_TAG_FOR_YOUR_PAGE").commit();
```

You may need to show the previous question to the user. Then do not remove your qa fragments and put them to backstack while adding them.

Comment: so let's say if I just copy and paste your code...you gave me three parts...I believe the first part is where I create a QAFragment class and of course in layout I should create like a qa.xml page with a few TextView and a RadioGroup then implement into your TODO like `RadioGroup gb = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio1)` then `setText` things like that?

Comment: your second code esp. the `SharedPreferences` part I don't quite understand :( sorry

Comment: Exactly. Use this code as a template and fill the TODO parts. I've edited my comment at second part. It was just an example to use sharedPreferences.

Comment: Have you succeeded on this?

Comment: I haven't try it yet didn't have time, kind of trying to learn on my own time :( but just by reading it, makes sense to me let me give it a check mark first ^_^

Comment: :( guess this is still a bit too advance for me :(

Comment: I don't think so. If you implement sth like this that will be easier to implement and maintain. Just read a little more about fragments;)

Comment: will try to read more about it in my free time :P thanks..should I read about fragments in the android development site or there's a better site you can recommend?